# Restarting X session shows screen blank for some time and comes up

Tags: 14.04, xorg, xserver, display-manager, xorg.conf

When I restart the X session using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in Ubuntu Machine , the X session is restarted and blank screen is showing up for some period of time(3 sec) and then the session comes up.

How to reduce the blank screen time which is displayed during the restart of X session?
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Three seconds isn't much time at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: thanks for help. Where do i find the timing parameters for X session.

Comment: @Sunny Timing parameters? The system attempts to re-spawn X as fast as possible. There are a *lot* of things that need re-initialization to get X running. Unless you're thinking of different timing parameters.

Comment: I mean which system file or process is responsible for loading the X session.

Comment: `xorg.conf`, and your display manager configs, as well as your DM configs. There are a lot of them.

Comment: hi kaz, Currently i am observing that the X session is restarted and blank screen is showing up for nearly 12 secs and then the session comes up. Is there a way to fine tune this time interval.